# When drawing multiple lines in applet, it shows only the last one

Tags: java, swing, canvas, applet

I am trying to draw multiple lines by using Java applet and canvas. I have defined class Canvas:

```
 public class Canvas extends JPanel {

    private static final int RIGHT=0, LEFT=1, UP=2, DOWN=3;
    public static final int WIDTH=600, HEIGHT=500;
    private int direction = 0 ;                          
    private int pixels;                             

    /**
     *  Canvas() constructor sets its size
     */
    public Canvas() {
        setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    }

    public void setPatt(int pat, int lev) {
        direction = pat;
        pixels = lev;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(getForeground());
        switch (direction) {
        case LEFT:  
            drawLineLeft(g, pixels); 
            break;
        case RIGHT:
            drawLineRight(g, pixels);
            break;
        case UP:
            drawLineUp(g, pixels);
            break;
        case DOWN:
            drawLineDown(g, pixels);
            break;
        } 
    } 

    private void drawLineLeft(Graphics g, int pix){

        if(pix > 0){
            Dimension d = getSize();
            int x = d.width/2;
            int y = d.height/2;
           g.drawLine(x, y, x-10*pix, y);//left
        }
    }

    private void drawLineUp(Graphics g, int pix){
        if(pix > 0){
            Dimension d = getSize();
            int x = d.width/2;
            int y = d.height/2;
            g.drawLine(x, y, x, y-10*pix);//up
        }
    }

    private void drawLineRight(Graphics g, int pix){
        //Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        if(pix > 0){
            Dimension d = getSize();
            int x = d.width/2;
            int y = d.height/2;

            g.drawLine(x, y, x+10*pix, y);//right
        }
    }

    private void drawLineDown(Graphics g, int pix){
        if(pix > 0){
            Dimension d = getSize();
            int x = d.width/2;
            int y = d.height/2;
            g.drawLine(x, y, x, y+10*pix);// down
        }
    }
}
```

I also have another class where I have defined drop down list, text field and button. I can choose direction from drop down list in which line should be painted (RIGHT, LEFT, UP, DOWN - direction) and I can define how long the line will be by typing a number in text field (pixels). When the button is pushed, method `setPatt` is called and line appears in canvas:

```
public class TurtleApplet extends JApplet implements ActionListener
{
    .....
    .....
    .....

    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e) 
    {
       if(e.getSource() == drawButton){
            int y = Integer.parseInt(pixels.getText());
            canvas.setPatt(direction.getSelectedIndex(), Integer.parseInt(pixels.getText()));

        }
       //repaint();
    }  
    .....
}
```

The problem is that when I push the button new line appears in canvas only then when I resize applet window. I tried to add `repaint()` method, this helped, but still there is another problem - how to make draw new line without losing the previous one?

Only the last line is visible on the screen, for example, when I draw a line to the left from center (line always starts from the center of canvas) and then I want to draw a new line to the right from the center, the line first line disappears and I can see only the second one and so on.

Comment: You should be calling `` before you do any custom painting

Comment: The real question is, why should it paint more then one line, when you only specify a single possible direction?

Comment: There are 4 directions,the beginning of the line on the center of canvas

Comment: What you should be doing, is maintaining a List of some sort with instructions (direction, lev), each time paintComponent is called, you should iterate over this list a paint each line. Remember, painting is destructive, you are expected to repaint the current state of the component when paintComponent is called

Comment: But you are only painting ONE direction, painting is NOT cumalitive, it is destructiive

Comment: You should have a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for a better understanding of how painting works

Answer (score 0):

You should keep track of lines drawn already. The `paintComponent` method supposed to print (or reprint) the entire component. As far as I see you always print just 1 line, therefore you loose the previous state.

Try to create a `Map<Integer, Integer>` where you store the line data and iterate through in the `paintComponent` method to draw all lines.

The method `setPatt` may be called `addPatt` instead.

PS: If the order matters, try `LinkedHashMap`

Comment: What happens if you have more then one line of the same direction? IHMO a POJO and a `List` would be better

Comment: Well, I agree with MadProgrammer, but the POJO sounds like overkill for such object invented a number of times ..
dreamPr
Try List<Dimension> to keep your points in it.